# For android How to create device theme NOT app theme?

Tags: android, android-theme

I know about creating theme for android app , but I don't know how to create a theme for the android system itself which is the theme that contains icons styles and wallpaper...etc .
I have searched a lot but I found nothing on that topic , so I appreciate answering my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that you want to create a completely new home widget, and a brand new application drawer. Your app doesn't change the icons or change the drawers, you have to create a new home app and build it fully functional. To host icons and things like that. Yours will replace the default android home application.

Comment: Most apps that do this are listed as "launchers" like Nova Launcher, which completely overhauls everything.

Answer (score -1):

You can start by creating an activity to replace default home screen as following in your app manifest.xml

`<activity
    android:name="ah.hathi.simplelauncher.HomeActivity"
    android:label="Simple Launcher Home"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>`

By adding the categories android.intent.category.HOME and android.intent.category.DEFAULT to the intent-filter group, when users click on home button, they will be asked to choose between default launcher or your activity. So you can custom your launcher activity as whatever you want.

The details could be found here : [build a custom launcher on android](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358)